# Having trouble using join function in SQL

Tags: sql, function, join, using

I'm trying to join two tables using the join function.

Workbench keeps coming up with an error and don't understand why.

Please help

```
select city, cityid, countryid
from cities 
join countries on cities.CountryID = countries.CountryID;
```

Comment: ***WHAT*** error?!?! We cannot read your screen, nor your mind - you'll have to **tell us** so we have any chance of helping you ! Also, for which *flavor* of SQL is this - MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? DB2? Something else?  Please provide a helpful tag !

Answer (score 0):

Since both tables have a column named `CountryID`, you have qualify which one you're selecting, i.e. either specify `cities.CountryID` or `countries.CountryID`.

```
select city, cityid, cities.countryid
from cities 
join countries on cities.CountryID = countries.CountryID;
```

(Doesn't matter which one you chose in this case, since the JOIN condition makes sure they have the same values.)

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend this syntax

```
SELECT 
 ci.city, 
 ci.cityid, 
 ci.cities.countryid
FROM 
 cities ci
 join 
 countries co on ci.CountryID = co.CountryID;
```

always use the names of the tables before the name of the columns

Comment: Typo, there's no `ci.cities.countryid`.